# Best way to make a character animation with WASD & Look to Mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We have a character that should walk around by pressing WASD keys. The character should walk towards north when pressing W, to the East when pressing D and so on.
If the user presses "W and D" at the same time, the character should move diagonally between North and East.

On top of this: The character should also look towards the mouse.

The goal is to make a zombie shooter, where the player can run away (e.g. to the south) while shooting at zombies that coming from the north.

Of course in this case the character would run backwards.

I understand that I have to make animations for walking forward & backward and sideways. But what if the user presses "W & D" and walks diagonally? Do I need to make diagonal animations, or is there a better solution for that case?

Comment: maybe try to blend sidewalk and straightwalk animations using blend tree?

Answer (score 1):

One animation of walking should be sufficient.

There are two issues to handle:

1. Character staring at the mouse position: [RotateTowards Method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html)
2. Play animation backward if needed: [Example](http://gyanendushekhar.com/2016/10/28/reverse-animation-play-unity3d/)